# Caching downloaded JSON data to SQLite database - is it a good idea?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, caching, serialization

In my app I have to download JSON data from numerous web services. The data classes I use are fairly complex ones (lots of properties, quite deep inheritance tree, etc.).

I intend to do caching, using a single db table, where I'd store the downloaded JSON data in a VARCHAR column (along with other meta-data containing columns). JSON serialization is being done with the Gson library.

It seems quite convenient to just dump the instances into JSON, and parse them again later when I need them. No need to create custom tables for every class, or write loads of custom serialization code. Also, I can do queries on the cache table this way.

The question: Is this approach an anti-pattern by any means?

Comment: It does seem strange to use a sqlite db as a file store--why not wait until you're ready to store the structured data represented by your json?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with this approach; however, I am going to recommend that you instead use the built in caching storage. See the section called "Saving cache files" in [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for more details.This way you don't hog any precious space if your JSON objects are large in the event of a low memory situation.