# Json storage vs Sqlite storage android apps

Tags: android, json, sqlite, mobile, storage

we need to develop an **android app** , that contains data (this data don't change after the installation- ie : all data is static) and i need to know what the best way to store data , **JSON or Sqlite** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What I should pick - JSON or SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028619/what-i-should-pick-json-or-sqlite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqlite, because if i wanted to share my data just in case later point of time with the other apps on the phone then i need content providers which deals with the sqlite not the json.

Answer (score 0):

Read about Realm, it's very handy SQL library that uses Java Pojo classes